# Decide whether there is a MST that contains some edges of 2 distinct edge sets

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm

Let G = (V, E) be a weighted, connected and undirected graph. Let T1 and T2 be 2 different MST's. Suppose we can write E = (A1 U B U A2) such that:
B is the intersection of the edges of T1 and T2, and
A1 = T1 - B
A2 = T2 - B

Assuming that every MST T in G contains all the edges of B, find an algorithm that decides whether there is a MST T that contains at least one edge in A1 and at least one edge in A2.

Edit: I've dropped the part that was here. I think that it does more harm than good.

Comment: Either the black box is a red herring, or the original poser of the question should refresh their knowledge of [matroids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid).

Comment: Hi, David. First of all we haven't learned what a matroid is, so I don't understand what you mean. I said that it's possible to use the algorithm described in the last paragraph, but you don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should sort your edge that the red edge is prefer to blue edge for choose.then you can use any MST algorithm same as  [Prim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm)'s algorithm :

> If a graph is empty then we are done immediately. Thus, we assume
>   otherwise. The algorithm starts with a tree consisting of a single
>   vertex, and continuously increases its size one edge at a time, until
>   it spans all vertices. Input: A non-empty connected weighted graph
>   with vertices V and edges E (the weights can be negative). Initialize:
>   Vnew = {x}, where x is an arbitrary node (starting point) from V, Enew
>   = {} Repeat until Vnew = V: Choose an edge {u, v} with minimal weight such that u is in Vnew and v is not (if there are multiple edges with
>   the same weight, any of them may be picked) Add v to Vnew, and {u, v}
>   to Enew Output: Vnew and Enew describe a minimal spanning tree

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'm sorry, but I think that I should have formulated my question differently. We need to find an algorithm that decides whether there is a MST T that contains at least one edge in A1 and at least one edge in A2.

Comment: so sort a1 & a2 then choose first edge in a1 & a2.now do algorithm for another edge.

Comment: How do you know that if there is another MST you will find it ?

Comment: do you want to find all of the mst in your graph?

Comment: No. We are given 2 different MST's: T1 and T2. We need to determine if there is at least one MST that contains edges from A1 and edges from A2 (and obviously, it means that the MST is different from T1 and T2).